# How to direct a Cloudflare registered domain to a Bluehost hosted site and specific page

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

(I've edited this to give the real URLs in case that is helpful)

Here's my situation:

- I purchased phillyjazzduo.com through Cloudflare
- I also have elipointer.com that was purchased through Bluehost and is hosted on Bluehost and is currently operational.

Here's what I need to do:

- When a user goes to phillyjazzduo.com, I want them to be directed to elipointer.com/pointer-lenox

Here's the steps I took:

- On Cloudflare I set up the following DNS records:

[DNS Records Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFXdJ.jpg)

- On Cloudflare, set up a page rule that forwards domain1.com/* to domain2.com/a_page:

[Page Rule Forward Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgfpP.jpg)

I believe this tells the domain register (Cloudflare) what hosted server to point to for phillyjazzduo.com, and then tells it to take any traffic to phillyjazzduo.com/* and redirect it to elipointer.com/pointer-lenox.

Have I got it right? Anything I'm missing? So far I haven't gotten this to work completely.  Everything works if I enter https://phillyjazzduo.com in the address bar, but if I enter [www.phillyjazzduo.com](http://www.phillyjazzduo.com) or phillyjazzduo.com, I get the following: "Error: Page cannot be displayed. Please contact your service provider for more details. (19)"

Thank you for any help! I'm certainly new to this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the page you're seeing `Error: Page cannot be displayed. Please contact your service provider for more details. (19)` is from your hosting provider, not Cloudflare. I think this is because they got a request for a domain (phillyjazzduo.com) they don't know.

You can solve this by making another page rule for [www.phillyjazzduo.com](http://www.phillyjazzduo.com).

You may also want to consider adding phillyjazzduo.com as an alias domain at your hosting provider. That way, you don't have to setup

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick and everything is working now.